# Android Studio 3.5.2 Emulator. How to View list of applications

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I cannot see the button to go in a list of setting and applications in android emulator.
There is only 3 tap button in the lower screen "Overview",  "Home", "Back"
And no button for apps-list.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hover mouse emulator screen > Click and Hold Left-Mouse Button > Drag up

Hope it helps!

Comment: When i click the screen and hold it begin to popup the menu "home, widgets, wallpapers"

Comment: However id alredy find a way to view the application list by: setting > display> add secondary display. But the problem of it is i can't hide  the default screen

Comment: Try clicking on the screen and dragging it up. Holding the mouse for too long causes the popup

Comment: No matter how fast I click/drag upward, I always get the Home settings, Widgets Wallpapers, this is driving me nuts, I git the problem since Bumblebee (or was it Big Sur) but the only remedy I saw so far was cold booting, so frustrating

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, no matter what or how fast i do the click and drag, it opens the home screen customisation popup(Wallpaper & Style, Widgets, Home Settings popup)
I can see the horizontal line in the bottom of the screen but dragging or clicking doesn't work.
Also tried using 3 finger drag and doesn't help either. I am using a MacBook pro(Apple silicon) with Version 12.4, Android studio chipmunk 2021.2.1

Comment: I can confirm that this doesn't work anymore (tested on pixel 5)

Answer (score 7):

It was totally obscure I've managed to do this on Pixel 2 Emulator:

1. Tap on the bottom search bar and hold
2. Move to top

Here is video: https://youtu.be/mnp0qSf4RnI
[image]

Comment: don't know why...but that worked on Nexus 6 Emulator (API 32)

Comment: Thanks 1000 times. How did you find out? Is it the same "obvious" interface in the real Pixel device?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot with the Android Pixel 2 and 7 emulators, the emulated location didn't work. The solution for me was: Pixel XL Api33 (Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1)

[image]